# how to link xmlsec/xmlsec.h in make file using c

Tags: c, linux

src/file.c:17:27: fatal error: xmlsec/xmlsec.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/file.o] Error 1

installed apt-get install libxmlsec-dev and after using locate command the location is usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec/xmlsec.h

Comment: LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/include/xmlsec1/xmlsec -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c -1m in makefile

Comment: Add `-I/usr/include/xmlsec1/` to compiler command line.

Comment: i have added this path(-I/usr/include/xmlsec1/) still it is not working..

Comment: Has something changed? Are are you still getting the same error message?

Comment: yes still i m getting this error...

Comment: Could you show full compilation log (including compiler calls)?

Comment: LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c

Comment: # GCC compiler
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2 -I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c
OBJ=src/file1.o src/file2.o src/file3.pb-c.o
all:$(OBJ)
  $(CC) -E  $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o src/file1.c src/file2.c src/file3.pb-c.c $@ $(OBJ) 
#
clean:
 rm -f *.o
 rm -f *.c
 this one is make file....

Comment: gcc -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG   -c -o src/file.o src/file.c
src/file.c:17:27: fatal error: xmlsec/xmlsec.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/file.o] Error 1
error is showing on console

Comment: The `-I/usr/local/include/xmlsec1` portion should go to the `CFLAGS` variable, not to `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: gcc: all: No such file or directory

Comment: Most likely, you have a malformed Makefile (the `all:` label is probably not on separate line). This is a completely different issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use pkg-config so that you can see the correct location of the headers etc...

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs xmlsec1
```

This should output something similar to:

```
-DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_SIZE_T
-DXMLSEC_NO_GOST=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 
-I/usr/include/xmlsec1  -DXMLSEC_OPENSSL_100=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_OPENSSL=1 
-I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxmlsec1-openssl -lxmlsec1 -lssl -lcrypto -lxslt  -lxml2
```

The error you are getting seems to simply be when header file cannot be located.